# How to forward send calls from one PassthroughSubject to another (i.e. PassthroughSubject chaining)?

Tags: swift, combine

Imagine I have an API for a class that uses a `PassthroughSubject` to receive its input:

```
class Logger {
  let log: PassthroughSubject<String, Never>
}
```

Normally I can emit a value by invoking `logger.log.send("test")`.

Now say I want to have my own logger that sits between this generic logger and my code:

```
class MyLogger {
  let log: PassthroughSubject<String, Never>
}
```

This should prefix the string, and then send any updates to Logger. Is there a way to chain the output from one PassthroughSubject (e.g. MyLogger) to another (e.g. Logger)?

I know I can do it this way:

```
let cancellable = myLogger.log.sink { 
  logger.log.send("[MyApp] " + $0)
}
```

However, that doesn't seem like the Combine-way of chaining things together. I was hoping there was an API I could use more similar to this one:

```
logger.log.subscribe(myLogger.log.map { "[MyApp] " + $0 })
```

However, that doesn't compile since I think the map is causing it to turn into a publisher instead of a subject:

> Instance method 'subscribe' requires that 'Publishers.Map<PassthroughSubject<String, Never>, String>' conform to 'Subject'

Is there a more declarative API for making one PassthroughSubject subscribe to updates from another (with support for mutations in between) besides relying on `sink`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you flip the order of the subscribe, it works:

```
let cancellable = myLogger.log
  .map { "[MyApp] " + $0 }
  .subscribe(logger.log)

myLogger.send("test") // will send "[MyApp] test" to logger.log
```

Having said that, modeling set APIs like this with Combine seems a bit odd, and the `Failure` data type seems to be ignored completely. E.g. if the log failed, there is no way to communicate back up the chain that it failed.

A better API might be a normal function, which returns an `AnyPublisher`:

```
class Logger {
  func log(_ string: String) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
}

class MyLogger {
  func log(_ string: String) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
    return logger.log(string)
  }
}
```